# Node.js: Efficiently reading a range of lines

Tags: node.js

I'm currently using Node.js and am wondering how one would read a range of lines from a large text file. An obvious solution would be like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
  var lines = data.split('\n');
});
```

However, that would involve loading the entire file into memory, which would be impractical for large text files, such as ones 100MB+.

In Bash, I would normally use `sed` for this case.

Comment: Since they are large files, do you want to stream the lines, say one line at a time, or read all Y-X lines into memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [lazy](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/):

```
var fs   = require('fs'),
    lazy = require('lazy');

var x = 23;
var y = 42;
var lines = (
   lazy(fs.createReadStream('./large.txt'))
     .lines
     .skip(x - 1)
     .take(y - x + 1)
);
lines.forEach(function(line) {
    console.log(line.toString('utf-8'));
});
```

Comment: `lines` is a lazy object whose values are evaluated when you retrieve them. I added an example that just prints the lines. You can do whatever else you want with them.