# Reading file nodeJS (from_Line number to end of file)

Tags: node.js, awk

I am writing nodejs application which requires to read from large files and generate data. Currently for reading somefiles i am using awk command where i am using last read line count.

```
awk 'NR>last_line_count' fileName;
```

Problem is that this will not work in windows.

Is there anyway i can read between two files using nodeJS API(from last line count to end of file)?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course: you can read the file from the start and skip as many lines as you need to.  This is the only way to do it, and is essentially what `awk` was doing for you before.  To make it portable, simply implement this step in JavaScript.

If your files are really huge and the above solution is too slow, you can try `lazy` to do it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926173/4323 .  This may be faster if it's implemented more efficiently (e.g. in C++) than the naive solution in JS.